# Access :id property from within Angular router module

Tags: angular, router

Odd question, but is it possible to access an :id property from within an angular routing module itself? I have a route with a child (for example, test/:id) and am trying to use the :id property from the path to set a title attribute in the data section of my child route. Is this possible? Would it be something like setting a variable to the current url and using that variable as the title? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The above two approaches given as a answer would work but if you change id in url while being on same route they will fail. Use this instead.**

```
constructor(private routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
}
public routeSubscription: Subscription;
public id: any
ngOnInit() {
   this.routeSubscription = this.routeSnapshot.paramMap.subscribe((dataMap) => {
        this.id = dataMap.get('id');
   });
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.routeSubscription) {
   this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
 const id  = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your child, you could access the :id from the parent as follows:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

const id  = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params['id'];
```